# Adjust user agent in Android with Volley

Tags: android, http, http-headers, user-agent, android-volley

I am wondering how to adjust the standard user agent in my http requests. I am using the Volley library and I KNOW how to

- set a new user agent
- retrieve the default user agent as a string (e.g. "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; sdk Build/ICS_MR0") => System.getProperty("http.agent")

What I DON'T know is:

- how to get the single elements this user agent is build of, so I can replace only the string "Dalvik/1.6.0" with a custom string.

Is that possible, or do I have to make a string replacement?

Thx

Comment: I only figured out how to get the "Dalvik", "1.6.0" and "Linux" part by using System.getProperty() with "java.vm.name", "java.vm.version" and "os.name". How do I get the rest?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the user agent globally for all requests sent via volley, here is my solution:

When you are initializing the volley request queue, instead of using the convenient method `Volley.newRequestQueue(Context);`, use the following snippet:

```
    private RequestQueue makeRequestQueue(Context context) {
        DiskBasedCache cache = new DiskBasedCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), DEFAULT_CACHE_DIR), DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
        BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork(new MyHurlStack());
        RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        queue.start();
        return queue;
    }

    public static class MyHurlStack extends HurlStack {

        @Override
        public HttpResponse executeRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
            if (additionalHeaders == null || Collections.emptyMap().equals(additionalHeaders) {
                 additionalHeaders = new HashMap<>();
            }
            additionalHeaders.put("User-Agent", "test_user_agent_in_volley");
            return super.executeRequest(request, additionalHeaders);
        }
    }
```

This solution assumes you are targeting api level >= 9, so we use the HurlStack

The reason why this works is because in `HurlStack.executeRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)` method, the stuff you add to the additionalHeaders would later be added to an HttpUrlConnection request property as in `connection.addRequestProperty(headerName, map.get(headerName));`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
***Build.FINGERPRINT*** contains all the information you need,
**https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html**

To get the individual parts, use the individual constant strings,

For detailed OS Version information use [Build.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Build;
public class MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i("Build","BOARD = "+Build.BOARD);
            Log.i("Build","BOOTLOADER = "+Build.BOOTLOADER);
            Log.i("Build","BRAND = "+Build.BRAND);
            Log.i("Build","CPU_ABI = "+Build.CPU_ABI);
            Log.i("Build","CPU_ABI2 = "+Build.CPU_ABI2);
            Log.i("Build","DEVICE = "+Build.DEVICE);
            Log.i("Build","DISPLAY = "+Build.DISPLAY);
            Log.i("Build","FINGERPRINT = "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
            Log.i("Build","HARDWARE = "+Build.HARDWARE);
            Log.i("Build","HOST = "+Build.HOST);
            Log.i("Build","ID = "+Build.ID);
            Log.i("Build","MANUFACTURER = "+Build.MANUFACTURER);
            Log.i("Build","MODEL = "+Build.MODEL);
            Log.i("Build","PRODUCT = "+Build.PRODUCT);
            Log.i("Build","RADIO = "+Build.RADIO);
            Log.i("Build","SERIAL = "+Build.SERIAL);
            Log.i("Build","TAGS = "+Build.TAGS);
            Log.i("Build","TYPE = "+Build.TYPE);
            Log.i("Build","USER = "+Build.USER);
            Log.i("Build","BASE_OS = "+Build.VERSION.BASE_OS);
            Log.i("Build","CODENAME = "+ Build.VERSION.CODENAME);
            Log.i("Build","INCREMENTAL = "+ Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
            Log.i("Build","RELEASE = "+ Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
            Log.i("Build","SDK = "+ Build.VERSION.SDK);
            Log.i("Build","SECURITY_PATCH = "+ Build.VERSION.SECURITY_PATCH);
            Log.i("$TAG#",Build.FINGERPRINT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("http.agent")` returns something like:

```
Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; Android SDK built for x86 Build/PSR1.180720.075)
```

It's possible to build all the parts of this using a combination of [`android.os.Build`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build) and [`java.lang.System.getProperty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)).

This is an example of what's in `android.os.Build` running on an emulator:

```
Build.BOARD = "goldfish_x86"
Build.BOOTLOADER = "unknown"
Build.BRAND = "google"
Build.DEVICE = "generic_x86"
Build.DISPLAY = "sdk_gphone_x86-userdebug 9 PSR1.180720.075 5124027 dev-keys"
Build.FINGERPRINT = "google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PSR1.180720.075/5124027:userdebug/dev-keys"
Build.HARDWARE = "ranchu"
Build.HOST = "abfarm904"
Build.ID = "PSR1.180720.075"
Build.MANUFACTURER = "Google"
Build.MODEL = "Android SDK built for x86"
Build.PRODUCT = "sdk_gphone_x86"
Build.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS = {"x86"} 
Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS = {} 
Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS = {"x86"} 
Build.TAGS = "dev-keys"
Build.TIME = 1541887073000
Build.TYPE = "userdebug"
Build.USER = "android-build"
Build.UNKNOWN = "unknown"
Build.VERSION.BASE_OS = ""
Build.VERSION.CODENAME = "REL"
Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL = "5124027"
Build.VERSION.PREVIEW_SDK_INT = 0
Build.VERSION.RELEASE = "9"
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT = 28
Build.VERSION.SECURITY_PATCH = "2018-09-05"
```

These properties are always provided by the Dalvik VM, according to Google's documentation:

```
file.separator = /
java.class.path = .
java.class.version = 50.0
java.compiler = Empty
java.ext.dirs = Empty
java.home = /system
java.io.tmpdir = /sdcard
java.library.path = /vendor/lib:/system/lib
java.vendor = The Android Project
java.vendor.url = http://www.android.com/
java.version = 0
java.specification.version = 0.9
java.specification.vendor = The Android Project
java.specification.name = Dalvik Core Library
java.vm.version = 1.2.0
java.vm.vendor = The Android Project
java.vm.name = Dalvik
java.vm.specification.version = 0.9
java.vm.specification.vendor = The Android Project
java.vm.specification.name = Dalvik Virtual Machine Specification
line.separator = \n
os.arch = armv7l
os.name = Linux
os.version = 2.6.32.9-g103d848
path.separator = :
user.dir = /
user.home = Empty
user.name = Empty
```

So, the default user agent appears to be composed of:

```
System.getProperty("java.vm.name")    // Dalvik
System.getProperty("java.vm.version") // 2.1.0
System.getProperty("os.name")         // Linux
"U"                                   // not sure where to get this
"Android"                             // or this, probably safe to hard code though
Build.VERSION.RELEASE                 // 9
Build.MODEL                           // Android SDK built for x86
Build.ID                              // PSR1.180720.075
```